# Convert ASP.NET Project to SDK style (framework 4.8)

Tags: asp.net, migration

I'm in the process of migrating a large ASP.net app based on .net framework 4.8.

At the moment I'm using the upgrade assistant extension for Visual Studio to migrate the projects to SDK style.

For class libraries it's working fine, but for my ASP.Net project containing an `IHTTPModule` it complains about missing static main method.

So I assume that it's not possible to convert an old ASP.NET project to SDK style?

Comment: I not done or attempted this, but if the project is a "asp.net webforms application", AND not a "asp.net webforms site", then from the docs, yes, you can convert and update such web forms "application". How to tell difference between the "application" and "web site" choice? If the project has a .sln file, then it is a application. Keep in mind that the migration assistant does not, can not, and will not upgrade webforms sites. (all it does is put a proxy .net core web server in FRONT of the site, and then over time you manually (by hand) convert the webforms to the .net core MVC format